# Open Filestream For Writing - fortify Path Manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

Looking to resolve a fortify finding (Path Manipulation) for resolving opening a file:

```
public FileStream OpenFile(string directory, string filename)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    string pathname = string.Empty;
    pathname = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
    fs = new FileStream(pathname , FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    return (fs);
}
```

This code runs in a .NET application, but DOES NOT write to a virtual directory.

The Fortify help / suggestion indicates white listing the valid directories, but that is tantamount to hard coding the directories in the application. It may be secure, but it is not a good programming practice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are trying to write to a virtual Directory on the Server.. you will need to lookup how to use `Server.MapPath` and use `/path/path/etc..` use forward slashes that point to your location 
for example if you want to write to the documents folder the you would do `fs.Write(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/SomeData.txt"))`

Comment: also here `pathname = Path.Combine(directory, filename);` you could do the following 
`pathname = Path.Combine(directory, Path.GetFileName(filename));` if you are only looking to return the FileName..

Comment: Can you please clarify "but DOES NOT write to a virtual directory." remark? What do you want to do - write to particular location on disk *outside* root of you app OR get this code to write *only* inside root of your app?

Comment: Alexi ---- yes, I want the code to write outside of a virtual directory. The directory is not only not the app directory, it is not a virtual directory at all.

Comment: You are getting this finding because this method accepts a "user provided" path and file name.  If an attacker were to send this method the parameters `directory=C:\Windows\` and `filename=notepad.exe` they could overwrite `notepad.exe` with something malicious if your application had write permissions to that file.

Comment: There can certainly be mitigating factors such as all callers providing sanitized data, but this method is marked public.  A good approach is to white-list the locations that this method is allowed to write to.

Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Manipulation

Answer (score 1):

@James Nix has provided the reason Fortify found a vulnerability (in a comment):

You are getting this finding because this method accepts a "user provided" path and file name. If an attacker were to send this method the parameters `directory=C:\Windows` and `filename=notepad.exe` they could overwrite `notepad.exe` with something malicious if your application had write permissions to that file. –  James Nix Jan 6 at 17:17

If you are interested in fixing the vulnerabilities, then you will need to:

1. If possible, change method signature from public to private.
2. Provide a fixed prefix to the provided file path (like "D:\Temp\" or Application("files_root") which you could add to your application configuration.
3. Do not allow "/" or "\" or ".." or ":" in the filename argument. Or just restrict to something like 8.3 if appropriate.
4. Do not allow ".." or ":" in the path argument. Or just restrict to the acceptable character range (a-z for instance).
5. Do not return the open FileStream object. You lose control over whether it is ever closed (Denial of Service vulnerability). Instead, get the data you need and close the FileStream before returning from the method.

If you want more targeted remediation advice, you need to describe what your application needs to do with this method.

Comment: I don't know why this was ever marked as answer --- fortify told me why I was getting the finding using the verbage provide by James Nix. I was (and still am) looking for a programmatic solution to the finding.

Comment: @Birdman I imagine it was marked as an answer because your implied question seemed to be, "Why is Fortify telling me this?" That is often the most difficult aspect of interpreting Fortify results.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add code to check "directory" and "pathname" to ensure of their existences on the system before calling FileStream.  For .NET, you can use the stat() function for the check.

Comment: Please consider adding examples and thorough explanation as to how this solves the issue.